# how can i disable compress when using riscv32 toolchain

Tags: gcc, embedded, riscv32

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHprD.png)

I need only `32-bit` instructions but `gcc` compile my `c` code with compressing.
I tried -march= options without c but compressed instructions still remain.
How can I get uncompressed(?) instructions?

Comment: As far as I can see, GCC hasn't an option to pessimize code that way. Why do you think this is desirable?

Comment: In my simple riscv core, core reads only 32-bit instructions. If there is 16-bit instructions , core reads concatenated instructions (16-bit instruction + 16-bit instruction ).

Comment: That does not explain to me why you don't want that. Surely the _core_ is able to correctly recognize two 16-bit instructions even if read at once, don't you think so?

Comment: @Armali No, some RISC-V cores (in particular, FPGA softcores) don’t support 16-bit instructions at all, that’s why the “standard extension for compressed instructions”, aka “extension C”, is an *extension*. The 16-bit instructions fit into holes in the 32-bit encoding, so the code won’t be misinterpreted, but on an unsupported implementation it’ll just take an invalid operation exception.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [GCC manual section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Options.html) on RISC-V command-line options, you can pass a standard RISC-V ISA subset name as specified in Vol. 1 Ch. 27 of the manual ([PDF](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/releases/download/Ratified-IMAFDQC/riscv-spec-20191213.pdf), [source](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/blob/master/src/naming.tex)) in `-march=`. For example, to compile for base 32-bit RISC-V with no extensions at all, add `-march=rv32i` to your compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

If you built the toolchain without multilib and included "C" in the arch during the build, the compiler will generate compressed instructions regardless of the march option having C or not, as some of the libraries are pre-compiled for the arch the arch you used while building.

rebuild the toolchain for a different isa config.